# The components in my routes are not displaying inside of my view does anyone see the issue

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to use vuerouter a bit more. I have set up everything and even in an external script page I house my scripts. I am using x-templates to alter the view so I am not sure what I am missing, I believe I have all the steps in place, but cannot figure why my router-view is not updating with the selected component.

```js
 
 
 
 
        const oneTemplate = {
            template: '#one',
            data() {
                return { title: 'oneTemplate' }
            },
            methods: {
                check() { this.checked = !this.checked; }
            }
        };



        
        const twoTemplate = {
            template: '#two',
            data() {
                return { title: 'twoTemplate' }
            },
            methods: {
                check() { this.checked = !this.checked; }
            }
        };



        const router = new VueRouter({
            routes: [
                { path: '/:year/:id/one', component: oneTemplate },
                { path: '/:year/:id/two', component: twoTemplate }
            ]

        })
 
 
 
 new Vue ({
        
            el:"#app",
           router,
            data:{
                status:'connected',


            }



           })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>


</head>
<body>


<div id="app">

        <router-link to="/one">My first component</router-link>
        <router-link to="/two">My Second COmponent</router-link>

    <router-view></router-view>
    <script type="text/x-template" id="one">
        <div>

            <div>
                page content will display here...
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>
 
</div>
```

Comment: I think your router-links dont match your routes. 

/one is different from /:year/:id/one

Comment: @DavidPi thanks! didn't realize it

Comment: Ill put it in answer then. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your router-links dont match your routes. 
/one is different from /:year/:id/one